# how to apply foreach loop in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Check the sql query bellow. Here in `SearchedUserItems` table there is a foreign key column named `SearchedUserID` which is primary key in another table called `SearchedUsers`. So basically in this query i am saying give me top 100 items from table `SearchedUserItems` which items have matching `SearchedUserID` from inner query list `select top 10 SearchedUserID from SearchedUsers`.
So this gives me top 100 items from all top 10 `SearchedUserID` matched but my goal is:
I want to get top 100 items from each `SearchedUserID` matched from `SearchedUsers` table. From current query i am getting total 100 matched items only but i need 100 items from each matched `SearchedUserID` from `SearchedUsers` table. How can i apply this `for each thing` in this query?

If you are not clear about question plz ask me. I tried my best to explain

```
select top 100 * from SearchedUserItems where SearchedUserID in (
select top 10 SearchedUserID from SearchedUsers
)
```

[Above query result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrb9I.png)

Comment: Use window functions (`row_number() ...`), do not forget specify ordering for all top N functions.

Comment: You are getting ten random SearchedUserIds, but not the top ten as defined by some quantity - you have no ordering criteria.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to explain here. Some sample data and expected results will *really* help us help you here. Also, your title mentions looping; this is something you should very likely be avoiding. SQL is a set based language, so it performs awfully at iterative tasks (and well, at set based ones, unsurprisingly). Finally, use of a `TOP` without an explicit `ORDER BY`, is generally a bad idea. This will return *x* arbitrary rows, and those rows can be different **every time** you run said query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my example you have two tables: A & B.
They are connected over column id from table A and A_id from table B.
In your question you are looking for top 100 records for each of top 10 records and in my example I am looking for top 2 records for each of top 2 records (I hope you understood this...)

```
select *
from ( select A.*
              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY  id DESC) rn
       from A 
       where ID in (select top 2 A_id 
                    from B 
                    group by A_id
                    order by A_id asc)) Table_C
where rn <= 2
```

Here you can see the query in action:
[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=976c039dcb4f38bfdb98c788589d25ca)